# Applying shadow effects to text in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am new to Objective-C programming. 
How can I apply shadow effects to text in Objective-C programatically?

This is my code:

```
[label setText:@"Some Text Data"];
[label setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];  
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaLTStd-Roman" size:19]];  
[label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:24.0f/255.0f green:24.0f/255.0f blue:24.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: So what problem you are facing??

Comment: If your background is white I think I know your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
[label setText:@"Downloading Data"];
[label setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
label.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaLTStd-Roman" size:19]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:24.0f/255.0f green:24.0f/255.0f blue:24.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```